# How to add a Loading Animation when a Button is Clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

For my website, when a button is clicked, the screen blurs.  I am now trying to add a loading animation of a spinning circle on top of that blur when the button is pressed, however, I'm running into a lot of issues.  When I tried to also have the button click have "isActive" and then make the loader class div when it isActive, the entire website crashed.

js file code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.scss";

class App extends React.Component {

    state = { fadingOut: false }
    fadeOut = () => this.setState({fadingOut: true});


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App" style={this.state.fadingOut ? {filter: 
            'blur(0.35vw)'} : undefined }
            > 

                <div className="top-bar">

                <div className="title">
                    .datapoems
                </div>

                <img className="logo" src="./logo.png"/>

                </div>

                <div className="container">
                    <div className="sloganLineOne">Poem Theme</div>
                    <div className="sloganLineTwo">Detector</div>
                    <textarea className="inputField" placeholder="Please Enter 
                     Your Poem Here..."></textarea>
                    <button className="button" onClick= 
                     {this.fadeOut}>Enter</button>
                    <img className="leftTriangle" 
                     src="./leftSideTriangle.png"/>
                    <img className="rightTriangle" 
                     src="./rightSideTriangle.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

scss loader code:

```
 .loader {
                border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
                border-radius: 50%;
                border-top: 16px solid blue;
                border-bottom: 16px solid blue;
                width: 120px;
                height: 120px;
                -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
                animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
              }

              @-webkit-keyframes spin {
                0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
                100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
              }

              @keyframes spin {
                0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
                100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

I took your code and modified it just a little bit to achieve your desired result (based on what I understood from your question).

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { fadingOut: false };
  fadeOut = () => this.setState({ fadingOut: true });

  render() {
    const contentStyle = this.state.fadingOut
      ? { filter: "blur(0.35vw)" }
      : undefined;
    const loadingIndicator = this.state.fadingOut ? (
      <div style={loaderStyle}>-- Loading icon --</div>
    ) : null;

    return (
      <div className="App" style={{ position: "relative" }}>
        <div style={contentStyle}>
          <div className="top-bar">
            <div className="title">.datapoems</div>
            <img className="logo" src="./logo.png" />
          </div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="sloganLineOne">Poem Theme</div>
            <div className="sloganLineTwo">Detector</div>
            <textarea
              className="inputField"
              placeholder="Please Enter Your Poem Here..."
            />
            <button className="button" onClick={this.fadeOut}>
              Enter
            </button>
            <img className="leftTriangle" src="./leftSideTriangle.png" />
            <img className="rightTriangle" src="./rightSideTriangle.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
        {loadingIndicator}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const loaderStyle = {
  position: "absolute", // or position: "fixed"
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "center",
  alignItems: "center"
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-353dg

Comment: that code works and puts the words "Loading Icon" when the button is clicked but is there a way for it to actually have my image and scss code with webkit animations?

Comment: You have to add scss-loader to webpack: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader (which, I suppose, you've already done it). Then replace the `-- Loading icon --` text with `<div className="loader" />`